# Function being detected also getting invalid syntax errors

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create an automatic otp generator most of the code is correct but only 1 part of it isn't working also if you can help me make it cleaner that would be of great help.

*The error I am running into is that the code isn't detecting my putinput function. Whenever I call it, it gives a Invalid syntax error*

```
import random
import sys

name = input("Enter your name: ")
email = input("Enter your email: ")
age = input("Enter your age: ")


def otpgen():
    otp=""
    for i in range(4):
        otp+=str(random.randint(1,9))
def check(inputvar):
    if len(inputvar) < 1:
        print("YOU CANNOT LEAVE A VALUE EMPTY")
        sys.exit()

def putinput():
    gl = globals()
    search = ''
    lst = []
    for var, empty in gl.items():
        if empty == search:
            lst.append(var)
    lenlst = len(lst)
    x = -1
    for i in lst and x <= lenlst:
        x += 1
        check(lst[lenlst - x]

putinput()
otpgen()
```

Comment: You are saying a syntax error can't you clear it by yourself. Even a complete newbie canadd a closing parenthesis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about adding a closing parenthesis at the end of your `def putinput():` function:

```
def putinput():
    gl = globals()
    search = ''
    lst = []
    for var, empty in gl.items():
        if empty == search:
            lst.append(var)
    lenlst = len(lst)
    x = -1
    for i in lst and x <= lenlst:
        x += 1
        check(lst[lenlst - x]) # closing parenthesis here
```